# Triggering the Eyedropper from a certain color property in UI directly or via code?

Tags: interface, grease-pencil, properties, operator, keymap

Im trying to trigger this eyedropper for this color property (the vertex color in Paint mode in Grease pencil):

[image]

The eyedropper is triggered when pressing `E` but only when the mouse is hovering the property.

I was wondering if I can trigger that eyedropper directly, without having to hover it.

If Im not wrong, the operator that is being called when pressing `E` is `ui.eyedropper_color`.

I tried to directly call `bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_color()` but -as Im not surprised- didn't work.

Any clue? Is it doable?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to trigger the eyedropper programmatically, but:

The idea behind triggering the eyedropper with `E` while hovering over the property is rather a byproduct of its real use: While hovering over the palettes in the `Tools`-Property panel, which makes much more sense.

So, open the `properties Panel` / `Tools` as shown in the image, hover over your desired color in the `Coler picker` or the `Palette`, press `E` and select your color.

[image: Color picker]

There are waaay too much functions in Blender to match the keyboard, and `E` is used in other contexts for different purposes (`Extrude`), so having keystrokes being limited to certain UI-Areas is one way to accomplish having more functions available as Keystroke-commands.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help friend! Indeed, is a good decission for having more functions in the same key. That eyedropper seems to me like some kind of intermediate/wrapper process for then triggering a color picker to a certain property (I was hoping we were able to kinda bypass that first 'step' but I think is not possible, I cant find anything in the API).
Thanks again :)